# Kotlin Cancels getParceableExtra call when passing data class using Intent

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, data-class

Trying to pass a data class `User` from one Activity to another using `Intent`.

**My putExtra looks like this using my observe fun:**

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("userData",userData)
            startActivity(intent)
```

**My get routine looks like this:**

```
userData = intent.getParcelableExtra<User>("userData") as User
```

**or**

```
userData = intent.getParcelableExtra("userData")
```

My problem is that Android Studio strikes out the function. My User data class is marked `@Parcelize`. It all ends up <strike>getParcelableExtra</strike>.

**I've add to my gradle build:**

```
id 'kotlin-parcelize'
```

I've read several posts about `Parcelable` being more modern than `Serialable`, so that's the technique I'm using. All the posts are from 2018 or prior and many of them in Java.

**How does one send an data class from one Activity to another using Intent?**

Comment: You can use JSON, Like convert your object to JSON then put the JSON in your intent to send it as String! , And when you want to receive it convert the JSON String to an object

Comment: I'm still a little unclear how to use Json to do this. I keep getting a string version of the object like "User(name=Fred)" which doesn't Json well. Does Gson know which object I'm sending in? This is the line I'm using: val temp = gson.toJson(userData). I get back "User(name\u003d8)" etc.

Comment: providerZ, thank you for your direction. It made the difference!

Comment: I'm here to help, I didn't receive your first comment because you didn't tag me with my username, Anyways, The idea of Gson is converting your object to a String and vice versa you don't have to know how exactly it does the converting or the format of the JSON string , Yes GSON does know your object by saving it with a key to receiving it from your next activity, You should easily find some resources on youtube how you do that step by step, If you want me to explain how to do it I am glad to help you on discord,It won't take me long to explain it, Greetings!

Comment: @providerZ - please keep all content here; don't promote moving conversations off this site.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sure, Whatever pleases you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getParcelableExtra (String name)` is deprecated from api level 33 you can use `getParcelableExtra (String name, Class<T> clazz)` from api level 33

In Your case use :

```
val userData =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        intent.getParcelableExtra("userData", userData::class.java)
    }
    else{
        intent.getParcelableExtra("userData") as userData?
    }
```

where TIRAMISU is constant value 33

To get more info:Read this:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getParcelableExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%3CT%3E)

Comment: thank you. any attempt in my code to access getParcelableExtra is struck out by the IDE and this is the the TIRAMISU line added. Not sure why. I'm targeting 33 with a min of 21. Maybe that's it. I have some older hardware I have to run on, so I used the string technique. Hopefully, putExtra won't cause me any issues. Appreciate the response!

Answer (score -1):

SOLUTION:

Given the need for compiler version 33 for the most modern solution, I went with a more backward compatible solution. This code translates the data object into a string, then back into the object.

**SETUP: (PUT)**

```
private var _userData = MutableLiveData<User>() // does the username and pw validate?
val userData : LiveData<User>
    get() = _userData
```

**SETUP: (GET)**

```
private lateinit var userData: User
```

**PUT CODE:**

```
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    val jsonUserData = Gson().toJson(userData)
    intent.putExtra("userData",jsonUserData)
```

**GET CODE:**

```
val jsonUserData = intent.getStringExtra("userData")
        userData = Gson().fromJson(jsonUserData, User::class.java)
```

Comment: This answer is not related to your question at all , You never mentioned the live data implementation in the question, But Dr. Tyrell since this works for you then I am happy for you , Greetings

Comment: It is. The command that I need to use doesn't work and there is no work around. You yourself suggest this solution.

Comment: Indeed, Would be better if the answer was more specific to the question, We solved the problem that what is important